# Write code that flip the nth bit

Tags: vhdl

As the title say I need to write a vhdl code that take as input a 32 bit vector and a 6 bit vector. I need to output another 32 bit vector which is equal the input 32 bit vector but the nth bit of it is flipped. n= the number of the 6 bit vector. Here is my code but is incorrect.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
entity flipMSB is
    Port ( Anotf : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
        count : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (5 downto 0);
       Af : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0));
 end flipMSB;

architecture bhv of flipMSB is
 signal sig: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
 signal n : integer;
 begin
 n<=CONV_INTEGER(count); 
 sig<=Anotf;
 sig(n)<=not sig(n);
 Af<=sig;
  end bhv;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a 6 bit number goes up to 64, you only need 5 bits for your `count` signal!

Second:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
```

`std_logic_arith` and `numeric_std` have conflicting types. Since `std_logic_arith` and `std_logic_unsigned` are not part of the VHDL standard (and IEEE, despite the library name), I suggest you only use `numeric_std`. If you use VHDL-2008, you can use `numeric_std_unsigned`. You will need to replace `n <= conv_integer(count)` with `n <= to_integer(unsigned(count))`

Finally,

```
 sig<=Anotf;
 sig(n)<=not sig(n);
```

will have two output driver for the bit `n`, which is bad. If you put that logic into a process, it would be fine since the first assignation to `sig(n)` would be overridden (instead of driven twice):

```
process(Anotf, count)
    variable n : natural;
begin
    Af <= Anotf;

    n := to_integer(unsigned(count));

    Af(n) <= not Anotf(n);
end process;
```

Think of it this way, if two processes drive the same signal, this result in two drivers (and conflict!). A statement outside a process is implicitly in its own process. Also, in a process only the last statement assigning a signal will have an effect.

Comment: thanks a lot! How can I know all of this ? Is there a book or something ?

Comment: Peter Ashenden "Designer's Guide to VHDL" ... IMO still the best.

Comment: @Jonathan : I think this implementation is broken unless you add "count" to the sensitivity list

Comment: @BrianDrummond is there a way I can write this code from hardware perspective? without using any software implementation ?

Comment: Thanks Brian! @user93765, what do you mean by hardware perspective? You would want to directly instantiate the technology's primitives?

Comment: A more "hardware" way would be to generate a mask  (32-bit slv) with only one bit set (teh bit indexed by "count"), then XOR the data with that. A good exercise would be to write this, and synthesise both versions. My guess is that they would produce essentially the same hardware...